# Python global common path for logger output

Tags: python, logging

I am dealing with a path problem in usage of logger. Well, I've createt a logger class which is located in file `logger.py` and all I want to do is to use the logger across my project. Here goes the structure:

```
project/
  /docs
  /log
  /dir1
    /dir2
      __init__.py
      a.py
      ...
    __init__.py
    b.py
    logger.py
    ...
  setup.py
```

Well, the problem is when I want to use logger in files `a.py` and `b.py`. I am unable to set logger ouput path properly. I found out that usage of relative paths is not the right way. How can I force the logger to put the log files `a.log` and `b.log` into the `/log` folder? Inside the `logger.py` file I am using `logging.FileHandler()`. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
`logger.py`:

```
class Logger:

   LEVEL = logging.DEBUG

   def __init__(self, name, logger_path, level=None):

       self.logger = logging.getLogger(name)

       formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s.%(lineno)d - [%(levelname)s] - %(message)s')
       file_handler = logging.FileHandler("{0}/{1}.log".format(logger_path, name))
       file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

       self.logger.addHandler(file_handler)

       if level:
           self.logger.setLevel(level)
       else:
           self.logger.setLevel(self.LEVEL)
```

Well I passed the relative path from `a.py` and it worked while I was running the script from the directory `/dir2`. But it doesn't work elsewhere in the project...

Comment: Without knowing more about how the loggers are defined, it's hard to give a specific answer. Presumably, `logger.py` contains some way of specifying `project/log` as the base directory for all logs. Each individual logger would then have to be configured with its own handler, something like `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__); logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler(logger.log_dir + "/" + __name__ + ".log"))`

Comment: @chepner I've updated it.

Comment: @marthin23 did you got the solution? I am stuck in a similar problem where I want to have a common path. In my project what's happening is it creates a new file where I start the python script, not where the project is installed.